# Take vs. Limit vs. Top, Sort vs. Order By

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Using traditional SQL for long time, used to `order by` and `limit`, `top` is MS own "limit" but more intuitive.

Here two Kusto queries share the same condition and order by (sorting, right?), only difference is return how many, 20 vs. 200. Result is surprising:

```
AzureDiagnostics | where Category contains "postgresql" | take 20  | order by TimeGenerated desc
```

[image]

```
AzureDiagnostics | where Category contains "postgresql" | take 200  | order by TimeGenerated desc
```

[image]

**top** is more consistence

```
AzureDiagnostics | where Category contains "postgresql" | top 2  by TimeGenerated desc 
AzureDiagnostics | where Category contains "postgresql" | top 20  by TimeGenerated desc
```

**Update**, thanks to @Yoni L, here is the summary:

1. Sequence of each `|` section matters. For instance, `|take 10 | order by x` will sort AFTER `take` which is random.
2. `take` = `limit` in terms of usage
3. `order by` = `sort by`
4. `top 10 by x [asc/desc]` = `order by x [asc/desc] | take 10` except `top # by x` uses much less memory and should be preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike `top`, for `take` and `limit` (which are aliases) there is no guarantee which records are returned, unless the source data is sorted.

The following are equivalent - `top 20 by x desc`, `order by x desc | take 20`, however this has different semantics: `take 20 | order by x desc` - it only orders the (up to) 20 records that were `take`n

Comment: So sequence inside statement matters.

Comment: What about `sort` and `order by`?

Comment: `sort by` and `order by` are aliases as well

Comment: terrific, I've updated my post with my understanding, thank you!